# Do the Invasion weapons have killstreak kits?

Tags: team-fortress-2

With TF2's [invasion update](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Invasion_update), they introduced four new reskins: [Batsaber](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Batsaber), [Giger Counter](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Giger_Counter), [Shooting Star](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Shooting_Star), and [C.A.P.P.E.R](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/C.A.P.P.E.R). All of them function identically to existing weapons in the game, some with just slightly different particle effects.

Before investing in these reskins, I would like to make sure they can have killstreak kits applied to them.

- Are there killstreak kits specific to these reskins, similar to how there are Big Kill killstreak kits (reskin of Revolver)? or;
- Can the base weapon's killstreak kit be applied to the reskin, similar to how there are no Nostromo Napalmer killstreak kits (it uses the Flame Thrower killstreak kit)? For example, could I apply a Pistol killstreak kit to the C.A.P.P.E.R? or;
- Are there no killstreak kits applicable to invasion weapons at this time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TF2 was updated on October 15th to include killstreak kits for all invasion weapons. These killstreak kits are separate from their non-reskinned counterparts, meaning there are separate Machina and Shooting Star killstreak kits.

Invasion killstreak weapons obtained before October 15th were due to a temporary bug a while ago where generic killstreak kits could be obtained, which allowed almost any item in the game (including hats) to have killstreaks applied to them.

Answer (score 3):

Having a quick look at the Community Market, it turns out **you can use Specialised Killstreak kits on them**. As of right now, there are two different Invasion weapons so far that have kits applied to them, those being the [Giger Counter](http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/440/Specialized%20Killstreak%20Giger%20Counter) and [Batsaber](http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/440/Specialized%20Killstreak%20Batsaber), proving that the weapons can have kits applied to them. The item descriptions even show that they have a visible sheen and active killstreaks.

It seems like the kits used on them may well be blank kits, which is proven by the fact that the Wrangler (the weapon that the Giger Counter is a reskin of) doesn't have any kits at all.

Comment: It's done using the blank kits that don't have an item specified. They can be applied to most (possibly any?) items, including hats. The only reason there aren't any Professionals of those two or any of the others on the market is because people haven't used the kits on them yet.

Comment: @JimMouer Fair enough. I might try doing a bit of testing as well anyways.

Comment: For reference, blank killstreak kits were a bug.  Since this was patched, there a finite number of them out there.

Answer (score 2):

We don't really know for sure yet, but [recent](https://www.reddit.com/r/tf2trade/comments/3old4y/q_can_killstreak_kits_for_the_pistol_and_bat_be/) [discussions](https://www.reddit.com/r/tf2/comments/3ok9jy/invasion_weapon_killstreaks/) suggest not. Blank killstreak kits can be used on the items.